# NSImage size not real size with some pictures?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, nsimage

I see that sometimes NSImage size is not real size (with some pictures) and CIImage size is always real. I was testing with this [image](http://naturelap.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/mystic-nature.jpg).

This is source code which I wrote for testing:

```
NSImage *_imageNSImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"<path to image>"];

NSSize _dimensions = [_imageNSImage size];

[_imageNSImage release];

NSLog(@"Width from CIImage: %f",_dimensions.width);
NSLog(@"Height from CIImage: %f",_dimensions.height);




NSURL *_myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"<path to image>"];
CIImage *_imageCIImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:_myURL];


NSRect _rectFromCIImage = [_imageCIImage extent];

NSLog(@"Width from CIImage: %f",_rectFromCIImage.size.width);
NSLog(@"Height from CIImage: %f",_rectFromCIImage.size.height);
```

And output is:

[image]

**So how that can be?? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?**

Comment: Thanks for the great Wallpaper!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`NSImage` `size` method returns size information that is screen resolution dependent. To get the size represented in the actual file image you need to use an `NSImageRep`. You can get an `NSImageRep` from an `NSImage` using the `representations` method. Alternatively you can create a `NSBitmapImageRep` subclass instance directly like this:

```
NSArray * imageReps = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithContentsOfFile:@"<path to image>"];

NSInteger width = 0;
NSInteger height = 0;

for (NSImageRep * imageRep in imageReps) {
    if ([imageRep pixelsWide] > width) width = [imageRep pixelsWide];  
    if ([imageRep pixelsHigh] > height) height = [imageRep pixelsHigh];  
}

NSLog(@"Width from NSBitmapImageRep: %f",(CGFloat)width);
NSLog(@"Height from NSBitmapImageRep: %f",(CGFloat)height);
```

The loop takes into account that some image formats may contain more than a single image (such as TIFFs for example).

You can create an NSImage at this size by using the following:

```
NSImage * imageNSImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize((CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height)];
[imageNSImage addRepresentations:imageReps];
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more question. Now I know real size, but NSImage is small in that size.. how to avoid this? I need to use NSImage. For Example I change NSView frame to real size of image but in that frame NSImage is drawned small.

Comment: I've made some changes to the answer that should help.

Comment: Nice. I've swift-ified this below for people who prefer that language :)

Comment: Great answer. I have been working with lots of image sets and I just encountered this for the first time. Looking through the image metadata I don't seeing anything that indicates the image should be read at a lower resolution. Also, it is a JPEG image, but contains TIFF metadata? Why does NSImage decide to use a smaller representation in some cases?

Comment: I just ran into a case where I read an 2008x1340 JPEG and NSImage reports its size to be a whopping 144576 x 96480. The imageRep pixels size is the correct 2008x1340. So much for choosing the largest. Hmmm...

Answer (score 7):

NSImage size method return size in points. To get size represented in pixels you need inspect NSImage.representations property that contains an array of NSImageRep objects with pixelWide/pixelHigh properties and simple change size NSImage object:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    __weak IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/username/test.jpg"];

    if (image.representations && image.representations.count > 0) {
        long lastSquare = 0, curSquare;
        NSImageRep *imageRep;
        for (imageRep in image.representations) {
            curSquare = imageRep.pixelsWide * imageRep.pixelsHigh;
            if (curSquare > lastSquare) {
                image.size = NSMakeSize(imageRep.pixelsWide, imageRep.pixelsHigh);
                lastSquare = curSquare;
            }
        }

        imageView.image = image;
        NSLog(@"%.0fx%.0f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Zenopolis for the original ObjC code, here's a nice concise Swift version:

```
func sizeForImageAtURL(url: NSURL) -> CGSize? {
        guard let imageReps = NSBitmapImageRep.imageRepsWithContentsOfURL(url) else { return nil }
        return imageReps.reduce(CGSize.zero, combine: { (size: CGSize, rep: NSImageRep) -> CGSize in
            return CGSize(width: max(size.width, CGFloat(rep.pixelsWide)), height: max(size.height, CGFloat(rep.pixelsHigh)))
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If your file contains only one image, you can just use this :

```
let rep = image.representations[0]
let imageSize = NSSize(width: rep.pixelsWide, height: rep.pixelsHigh)
```

image is your NSImage, imageSize is the image size in pixels.

Copied and updated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228091/3608824

Answer (score 1):

`NSImage`'s `size` param returns size information dependent to screen resolution and scaling configuration.

Real size of image you can get with the following extension:

```
extension NSImage {
    var sizeReal: NSSize {
        guard representations.count > 0 else { return NSSize(width: 0, height: 0) }
        
        let rep = self.representations[0]
        return NSSize(width: rep.pixelsWide, height: rep.pixelsHigh)
    }
}
```