# Get the correct image width and height of an NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I use the code below to get the width and height of a NSImage:

```
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:s]] autorelease];
imageWidth=[image size].width;
imageHeight=[image size].height;
NSLog(@"%f:%f",imageWidth,imageHeight);
```

But sometime `imageWidth`, `imageHeight` does not return the correct value. For example when I read an image, the EXIF info displays:

```
PixelXDimension = 2272;
PixelYDimension = 1704;
```

But imageWidth, imageHeight outputs

```
521:390
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Dimensions of your image in pixels is stored in NSImageRep of your image. If your file contains only one image, it will be like this:

```
NSImageRep *rep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];
NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(rep.pixelsWide, rep.pixelsHigh);
```

where **image** is your NSImage and **imageSize** is your image size in pixels.

Answer (score 10):

NSImage size method returns size information that is screen resolution dependent. To get the size represented in the actual file image you need to use an NSImageRep.

Refer [nsimage-size-not-real-size-with-some-pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264051/nsimage-size-not-real-size-with-some-pictures) link and get helped

Comment: Hii Price,in iOS How to get size information that is screen resolution dependent? Have you any idea? then plz help me.

Answer (score 4):

the direct API gives also the correct results

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [oldImage CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:context hints:nil];
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
```

Comment: This appears to be the only correct answer when running on a Retina screen.  NSImage lies (what it returns might depend on the DPI that the image data declares), NSImageRep lies (it will return 2x the true pixel size when on Retina); only CGImage gives the actual size of the image in pixels.  I haven't been able to find any other way to get that information, on macOS 11.

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses a point system based on DPI to map points to physical device pixels.  It doesnt matter what the EXIF says, it matters how many logical screen points your canvas has to display the image.

iOS and OSX perform this mapping for you.  The only size you should be concerned about is the size returned from UIImage.size

You cant (read shouldnt have to shouldnt care) do the mapping to device pixels yourself, thats why apple does it.

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4**

You have to make a `NSBitmapImageRep` representation of the `NSImage` to get the correct pixel height and width. 
First a this extension to gather a `CGImage` from the `NSImage`:

```
extension NSImage {
    @objc var CGImage: CGImage? {
        get {
            guard let imageData = self.tiffRepresentation else { return nil }
            guard let sourceData = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) else { return nil }
            return CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(sourceData, 0, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to get the height and width:

```
let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: (NSImage(named: "Your Image Name")?.CGImage)!)
let imageHeight = rep.size.height
let imageWidth = rep.size.width
```

Answer (score 1):

i make a extension like this:

```
extension NSImage{
    var pixelSize: NSSize?{
        if let rep = self.representations.first{
            let size = NSSize(width: rep.pixelsWide, height: rep.pixelsHigh)
            return size
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```