# NSImage Image Size With Multiple Layers

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion, nsimage

I have a **Mac** (not iOS) application that allows the user to select one or more images with **NSOpenPanel**.  What I have trouble with is how to get correct dimensions for multiple-layered images.  If an image contains one layer or compressed, the following will get me correct image dimensions with the file path.

```
NSImage *image0 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
CGFloat w = image0.size.width;
CGFloat h = image0.size.height;
```

But if I select an image that has multiple layers, I'll get strange numbers.  For example, I have a single-layer image whose dimensions are 1,440 x 900 px according to **Fireworks**.  If I add a small layer of a circle and save an image as **PNG** and read it, I get 1,458 x 911 px.  According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264051/nsimage-size-not-real-size-with-some-pictures) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739165/nsimage-size-is-wrong), they suggest that I read the largest layer.  Okay.  So I've created a function as follows.

```
- (CGSize)getimageSize :(NSString *)filepath {
    NSArray * imageReps = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    NSInteger width = 0;
    NSInteger height = 0;
    for (NSImageRep * imageRep in imageReps) {
        if ([imageRep pixelsWide] > width) width = [imageRep pixelsWide];
        if ([imageRep pixelsHigh] > height) height = [imageRep pixelsHigh];
    }
    NSSize size = CGSizeMake((CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height);
    return size;
}
```

Using the function above, I get wrong dimensions (1,458 x 911 px) instead of 1,440 x 900 px.  Actually, I had the same problem when I was developing Mac applications with REAL Stupid till a few years ago.  So how can I get correct dimensions when an image contains multiple layers?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: if you open that PNG using Apple's Preview app, is the size of the image 1440 x 900 or is it 1458 x 911?

Comment: That's a good point.  It's 1,440 x 900 px, according to Preview's General Info.

Comment: I think I now know why the app gives me odd numbers.  The image DPI appears to be 71.12.  The original image was generated with sips (shell).